# windows server 2016 DC + VPN Roles - DNS Issue

Tags: domain-name-system, rras

I have a server running Windows Server 2016 with ADDS, DNS, DHCP and RRAS roles.
I am experiencing the following issue:

My server's LAN IP is 192.168.0.1 and the second interface, connected to DMZ, has IP 192.168.18.1.

The clients sometimes resolve the server's name with IP 192.168.18.1, I have noticed that the record is automatically created in DNS Server in the direct zone "my.domain.com" (even if the ".18" IP is fixed and not DHCP assigned)
Each time I delete the record 192.168.18.1 all connections from clients to the server works, until the record gets automatically recreated.

When the record gets re-created this issue starts happening again (as LAN clients have no routes to the DMZ IP).

How can I prevent the wrong record to be automatically recreated on the dns server?

Or is there any other kind of fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DNS server will register the ip address for each interface that it is bound to. The fix is to "unbind" the 192.168.18.1 interface in the DNS server properties.

From the DNS management console, right click the server, select properties from the context menu, and on the interface tab select the **Only the following ip addresses** radio button, and uncheck the 192.168.18.1 box.

[image]

Comment: I have solved with first answer, because i don't need to have DNS on my DMZ.

Answer (score 1):

Server 2016 introduced DNS policies, with DNS policies you can dictate which IP Address is resolved for a request. So for your network you can use them to make sure that when the clients query for the IP Address of the server they will always get 192.168.0.1

Here is a link with some details.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/dns/what-s-new-in-dns-server#dns-policies

Comment: I'm up voting this too as it is the best and most sophisticated solution, but I think it's just worth if you need domain DNS on the DMZ side. If you don't, the unbind one is the quickest and most effective for sure.